# A humane way to hold a group of elemental manipulators prisoner

Tags: internal-consistency, magic, super-powers

Using only current technology we have already created a way to hold prisoner a group of individuals who can manipulate the elements (fire/heat, earth, water/liquid, metal, lightning/plasma) with a certain level of humanity.

**Level of humanity**: Prisoners are required to be provided with enough food, water, exercises and human interaction to keep them in relative health and sanity. Nothing can be done to them that would cause permanent physical or physical logical injury.

**Notes**: Elemental manipulators have to move their body to manipulate the elements. Most do this by moving their hands but with practice they can manipulate elements by only twitching their neck or bodies.

Manipulate the elements by itself does not require a lot of concentration, but to do so with any form of skill or accurate dose. the more complex the action you want the element to do the more concentration you will need.

None of the guards in your prison have elemental powers.

Comment: So how this manipulation works? It differs from author to author. Even number of elements change from tradition to tradition

Comment: What is a physical logical injury?

Comment: I'm not sure what your actual question is here. If you've "already created" a humane way to hold these people prisoner, then what are you asking for exactly?

Comment: seems he means physical and mental injury

Comment: Can they make something up from the thin air? Especially for the Fire user

Comment: @L.Dutch Mistype of psychological at a guess.

Comment: @Bellerophon that or physiological, that's why I did not edit it

Comment: We need more information, Could earth control concrete? They have enough tech to implant bombs in they bodies?

Answer (score 3):

Prolongued detention is never healthy, both from the physical and from the psychological point of view (I assume you mean this when you say "physical logical", and not physiological). Therefore, don't let them feel prisoner, but rather "guests".

Implant them with a tracking device without them knowing it.

Let them free to roam a city where they can be quickly reached and kept under discreet and constant surveillance. Enforce controls and authorization on any other movement.

Nothing much different from what KGB did with any Westerner visiting USSR during the cold war. As tracking device they used to spread radioactive dust on the target's door mat.